# empty jquery element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an elegant way to create an empty jquery element (versus null) ?

```
$myEmptyElement = $("#ThisIdDoesNotExist234343");
```

The rational is not checking later on for null.

Later we do :

```
$myEmptyElement.destroy();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
var $emptyElement = $();
```

Why would you want one, though?

Comment: so we don't need to handle a null case

Answer (score 2):

A simple example would be:

```
var $emptyElement = $();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
var $emptyElement = new $;
```